# How accurate is reverse geocoding in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've been doing some reverse geocoding using the `MapLocationFinder` and sometimes the resolved street address number doesn't match the real one.

```
    private static async Task<MapLocation> GetLocationName(Geopoint geoPoint)
    {          
        var result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geoPoint);

        if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success && result.Locations.Count > 0)
            return result.Locations[0];

        return null;
    }
```

Any idea why this happens? I should also mention that this is not regular, most of the times the street number is right, but sometimes it produces a wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you cannot expect a reverse-geocoded address to match the real postal address at the location to the precision of the exact house number. It may only be possible in special cases, where geocoding data is available at the "parcel level" and the original lat/lon position fits reliably within the parcel boundaries. In the general case, your street number will only match something within the city block.